# How can I dynamically change the time (which is plain text) using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

[On this website](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136) the textual time is dynamically updated, I'm guessing using JavaScript.

This is the html code, using Firebug to inspect the page ...

```
<strong class="big" id="ct">Friday, 3 September 2010 at 8:17:21 AM</strong>
```

with that time value incrementing each second.

I'm guessing some JavaScript updates the 'ct' element .. but I can't find the code to how that's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javascript code on this page is obfuscated and that't probably why you can't find it. To achieve this you could use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) function:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#ct').html(new Date().toString());
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: notice how you used `new Date()` ... what happens if i have my OWN date .. can that be used instead?

Comment: You could pass this date to the [constructor of the Date](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp) object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use setTimeout method as follows:

```
function updateTime() {
    var dtString = new Date().toString();
    $('#lblDate').html(dtString);
    setTimeout(updateTime,1000);
}
updateTime();
```

It's different than setInterval. setTimeout must be called again in each function call to make  it work like setInterval.