# How to figure out how to use setInterval correct with this jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

This is a continuation of a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633739/how-can-i-dynamically-change-the-time-which-is-plain-text-using-javascript-or-j).

I'm trying to display a clock based on a pre-determined time value .. not the current *clients* time.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentTime = new Date('3/09/2010 9:27:29 PM');
    setInterval("DisplayTime(currentTime, $('.answer-body'))", 1000);
})

function DisplayTime(currentTime, destination) { ... }
```

Now inside the `DisplayTime` function, i was showing some custom text, calling the `destintion.html(..)` to display that custom text. And finally, after I display the text, I was thinking of adding *1 second* to `currentTime` so when the next iteration of the interval, it's not using the original time value, but 1 second later.

Problem: I cannot pass in the `currentTime` variable to the setInterval function. I don't particularly want to have an anonymous function here, unless I have no choice.

How can I refactor my bad code?

So every second, the time is re-displayed with the new second being added.

Answer (score 5):

On the contrary, you *should* use an anonymous function here, like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  DisplayTime(currentTime, $('.answer-body'));
}, 1000);
```

Don't ever pass a string to [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) or [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) if you can avoid it, it performs an `eval()` and has scope issues, like the one you're currently experiencing, since `currentTime` isn't a global variable.

Comment: Awesome @Nick Craver :) I just added `currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 1000);` (nod to @Matthew Flashcen) and boom - she works :) thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentTime = new Date('3/09/2010 9:27:29 PM');
    var destination = $('.answer-body');
    function DisplayTime()
    { 
      destination.html(currentTime);
      currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + 1000);
    }
    var id = setInterval(DisplayTime, 1000);
})
```

This uses a function (closure) within a function, but not an anonymous one.  `DisplayTime` will not be accessible from outside scopes.  There's no real reason to dislike anonymous functions, used appropriately.  I would use one here.